# RxJava2 not executing chain within MVVM architecture

Tags: android, performance, mvvm, rx-java, rx-java2

We have got the following code in `LoginViewModel`:

```
private MutableLiveData<Response> loginLiveData;

@Inject
public LoginViewModel(LoginUseCase loginUseCase) {
    loginLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    this.loginUseCase = loginUseCase;
}
@Override
public void onAttached() {
    checkHasToken();
}

public void checkHasToken() {
    add(loginUseCase.hasToken()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnComplete(() -> Timber.d("doOnComplete"))
            .doFinally(() -> Timber.d("doFinally"))
            .doOnDispose(() -> Timber.d("doOnDispose"))
            .doOnTerminate(() -> Timber.d("doOnTerminate"))
            .doOnError(Timber::d)
            .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> Timber.d("doOnSubscribe " + disposable.isDisposed()))
            .subscribe(
                    () -> {
                        loginLiveData.setValue(Response.success());
                        Timber.d("Subscribe completable");
                    },
                    t -> {
                        loginLiveData.setValue(Response.error(t));
                        Timber.d("Subscribe error");
                    }
            )
);
}
```

`hasToken()` is just checking if token exists inside `SharedPreferences`:

```
public Completable hasToken() {
    return !TextUtils.isEmpty(rawToken()) ? Completable.complete() : Completable.error(new Throwable("TokenIsEmpty");
}
```

And code that runs successfully, as shown in logs:

```
D/LoginViewModel: doOnSubscribe false
D/LoginViewModel: doOnComplete
D/LoginViewModel: doOnTerminate
D/LoginViewModel: Subscribe completable
D/LoginViewModel: doFinally
```

Nevertheless, once in a few times nothing is executed and the logs look as following:

`D/LoginViewModel: doOnSubscribe false`

AND THAT IS ALL!
Screen is stuck on this point, and does not proceed its further logic. 
It also takes place on other screens.

My base `ViewModel` looks like this:

```
public abstract class AbsViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

private static CompositeDisposable disposables;

public AbsViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
}
public AbsViewModel() {
    super(null);
}

public void onAttached() {}

@Override
public void onCleared() {
    dispose();
    super.onCleared();
}

public static void add(Disposable disposable) {
    getCompositeDisposable().add(disposable);
}

protected void dispose() {
    disposables.dispose();
    disposables.clear();
}

public static void dispose() {
    Timber.d("dispose");
    getCompositeDisposable().dispose();
}

private static CompositeDisposable getCompositeDisposable() {
    if (disposables == null || disposables.isDisposed()) {
        disposables = new CompositeDisposable();
    }
    return disposables;
}
```

Asking for help, because the chain is only subscribed to, and further execution is not reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `static CompositeDisposable disposables` in `AbsViewModel` that is the cause of that strange behavior. It's not good idea to do that, because all instances of `ViewModel` have access to **the same** instance of `disposables` - can `dispose()` and recreate it.

Let's look at example: we have 2 screens with separate `ViewModel` (extended from `AbsViewModel`). When you switch from first screen to second and go back to first screen, you will get next trace:

1. Screen1 `ViewModel.attach()`
2. Screen2 `ViewModel.attach()`
3. Screen1 `ViewModel.attach()`
4. Screen1 `ViewModel.onCleared()` which triggers `disposables.dispose()`

In that case in step(3) you will recreate `disposables` and add new one, but immediately in next step (4) you will dispose it.

It's only one of possible scenarios, that points out the problem of `static` disposables, shared between all instances of `AbsViewModel`. If you remove `static` modifier from `disposables` and all methods that work with it - you problem will disappear.